# Node.js path.join reverse operation

Tags: node.js, path

Example in Node.js API

```
path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

But how to get "/foo/bar" from '/foo/bar/baz/asdf' and ''baz/asdf'' ?

```
path.magic('/foo/bar/baz/asdf', 'baz/asdf')
//Returns: '/foo/bar/'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no native method for doing that.

I think the best way to do that is to use
`path.join('/foo/bar/baz/asdf', '..', '..');`

you can make your own function like below

```
const magic = function(originalPath, removePath) {
  let arr = removePath.split('/').filter((p) => p !== '').map(() => '..');
  return path.join(originalPath, ...arr);
}
```

You might need to use `path.sep` instead of `'/'` to support various OS.